# Vue.jsがうまくいきません

Tags: vue.js

vueと生のJSを使ってクリックすると内容が変化するようにしたかったのですが、うまくいきません。

```
app = Vue$3 {_uid: 5, _isVue: true, $options: Object, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: Vue$3…}
```

と出てしまいますがこれはエラーでしょうか？

vueは生の関数は使えないが文法は使えると聞いているのですが、イベントリスナーやgetelementは使えないのでしょうか？

```
var changeBtn = document.getElementById('changeBtn');

changeBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

var app = new Vue({
el: '#headding',
data: {
headding: '当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。'
}
});

var app = new Vue({
el: '#description1',
data: {
description1: '当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。'
}
});

var app = new Vue({
el: '#description2',
data: {
description2: '当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。'
}
});
});
```

初心者なので、初心者でもわかるように教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: 了解しました返信は取り消したのでマイナスを取り消してください

Answer (score 3, accepted):

記述されているコードを実行してもエラーは出ませんでしたが、同じ変数名（ `var app` ）を何度も定義していることや、複数のVueインスタンス(`new Vue({...})`) が存在することが影響しているのではないかと思います。

また、Vue.js を使う場合は特別な理由がなければ生のJSを使う必要はないので、
例えば少し整理して書いてみると:
（上のコード見た限り、ボタンをクリックすると文章が表示されるような感じでしょうか）

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    headding: '当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。',
    description1: '1. 当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。...',
    description2: '2. 当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。...',
    show: false
  },
  methods: {
    change: function() {
      this.show = !this.show
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.1/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-show="show">
    <div v-text="headding"></div>
    <div v-text="description1"></div>
    <div v-text="description2"></div>
  </div>
  <button @click="change">
    クリックしたら文章が表示される
  </button>
</div>
```

というように書けます。

どうしても生のJSでクリックイベントを書きたい場合は以下のように書けます:

```
/* var app = new Vue({...}) の下側に書きます */
var changeBtn = document.getElementById('changeBtn');
changeBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  Vue.set(app, 'show', !app.show)
})
```

Comment: 編集してお返事を書きました。

Comment: 読みました。`change() {}` は混乱を避けるため `change: function() {}` に書き換えました。`addEventListener` の件は最後に少し書いている通りです。新しい質問に関しては、質問のコメント欄に指摘がきているので、それに従ったほうがよいかなと。

Comment: Vue.set(app, 'show', !app.show)
こちらは、<div id="app">の中の<div v-show="show">の値showに対して何かを行うという事でしょうか？

!app.showは<div id="app">の中の<div v-show="show">だけは何かをしないという言ことですか？
こうすると、DOM操作だけにvueを導入してその他は生のJSで済むと考えてよいのでしょうか？

Comment: `Vue.set()` を使うと `new Vue(...)` の外から内部のデータを変更することができます。
`Vue.set(app, 'show', !app.show)` の意味は、 `app = new Vue({...})` の中にある `show` というデータに `!app.show`（`show`を反転（`show`が`true`なら`false`, `false`なら`true`）したもの）を設定する、ということになります。
例えば、`Vue.set(app, 'headding', 'あああ')` とすれば `headding` のテキストを変えられます。
外から変更できるので、別のファイルに分けることも可能です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

>>>
Vue.set(app, 'headding', 'あああ') とすれば headding のテキストを変えられます

つまり、引数の１変数名　この変数の中の
２　このプロパティの
３　２で指定したプロパティの値をここで指定した文字列などに変更するという意味でよいでしょうか？

これはテキスト限定ではなくurlなどでも良いのですかね？




＞＞＞
 !app.show) の意味は、 app = new Vue({...}) の中にある show というデータに
 !app.show（showを反転（showがtrueならfalse, falseならtrue）したもの）を設定する、ということになります。
 
難しいですね。下記と同じことをやっているという事でしょうか？
this.show = !this.show
第三引数は真偽値なのですか？

Comment: `Vue.set()` の認識はそれで間違いないです。第3引数はテキストでなくても配列やオブジェクトでも構いません。反転の件ややこしくてすみません。真偽値です。`this.show = false` などとしているのと変わりません。この場合は条件文で判定しないといけませんが。

Comment: ありがとうございました。助かりました。

Answer (score 0):

`data:{}`内で宣言されているプロパティを変更するにはただ代入します。`Vue.set`の必要性は次のURLに書かれてあり`new Vue(...)`の外か中かは無関係です。https://jp.vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/

どうしても生のJSでクリックイベントを書きたい場合で、マウント要素の外にボタンを置く例:

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-show="show">
    <div v-text="headding"></div>
    <div v-text="description1"></div>
    <div v-text="description2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="changeBtn">クリックしたら文章が表示される</button>
<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    headding: '当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。',
    description1: '1. 当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。...',
    description2: '2. 当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。...',
    show: false
  }
});
var changeBtn = document.getElementById('changeBtn');
changeBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  app.show = !app.show;
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
app.show = !app.show;とは
var appの中の始めから存在する？showオブジェクト？がtrue（初期値）だったら、クリックした際にdata内を実行する
そして一度押したときにshow: falseにしているのでもう一度押すことはできない。
という意味でよいでしょうか？