# Vueのクリックイベント時に式を実行させることがうまくいきません。

Tags: vue.js

[Vue.jsがうまくいきません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/36137/vue-js%e3%81%8c%e3%81%86%e3%81%be%e3%81%8f%e3%81%84%e3%81%8d%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93)
の続き

前回の質問で教えていただいたことを参考に下記のように変更を行ったのですが、やはりうまくいきません。

```html
<button @click="change"> </button>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#changeBtn2',
  data: {
    headding: '当社のダミー商品１つめを紹介します。',
    description1: '1. 当社のダミー商品１つめを紹介します。...',
    description2: '2. 当社のダミー商品１つめを紹介します。...'
    // show: false
  },
  methods: {
    change: function() {
      headding: '当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。',
    description1: '1. 当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。...',
    description2: '2. 当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。...'
    }
  }
})
```

---

#### 追記

[mjy さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/36573/19110)を元に書きなおしたのですが、やはりうまくいきません。

```html
    <button @click="change"> </button>

    <p id="description1">
    {{ description1 }}
</p>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#changeBtn1',
  data: {
    headding: '当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。',
    description1: '1. 当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。...',
    description2: '2. 当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。...'
    // show: false
  },
  methods: {
    change: function() {
        headding= '当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。';
        description1= '1. 当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。...';
        description2= '2. 当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。...';
        },
  },
});
```

Comment: 「うまくいかない」ということを説明するためには、したいことと、今の状況と、望ましい状況と何が違うのかの3点を質問文に含めると説明しやすいと思います。このスクリプトを動かしたときのどの動作が想定と違うのかを本文に書いてみてください。また、スクリプトに小さな打ち間違いがあるようです。

Comment: やりたいことはmjyさんの提示されたものその物です。タイプミスがどうしても見つかりません。ご存知なら記載いただけませんか

Comment: 瑣末なことですが、最初の button タグが閉じていません。（スクリプトと言ったのが悪かったかもしれません、すいません）

Comment: 今回の件とは関係ない部分ですがのちの方のために修正しておきました

Comment: ちなみに、最初の表示がうまくいかないんでしょうか？それともボタンをクリックしても反応しないということでしょうか？

Comment: @Kesuiketお返事いただいていることに今今気づきました。現在色糸いじっているので両方に問題がありますが、いじる前は表記はちゃんとできているがクリックをしても変化がない状態でした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問者さんのやりたい事を[Kesuiket さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/36430/3054)から類推して書き変えると下記のようになるかと思います。

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    headding: '当社のダミー商品1つめを紹介します。',
    description1: '1. 当社のダミー商品1つめを紹介します。...',
    description2: '2. 当社のダミー商品1つめを紹介します。...',
  },
  methods: {
    change: function() {
      this.headding = '当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。';
      this.description1 = '1. 当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。...';
      this.description2 = '2. 当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。...';
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.1/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div v-text="headding"></div>
    <div v-text="description1"></div>
    <div v-text="description2"></div>
  </div>
  <button @click="change">
    クリックしたら文章が変更される
  </button>
</div>
```

どこが悪かったかというと、このメソッドの定義です。

```
change: function() {
  headding: '当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。',
description1: '1. 当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。...',
description2: '2. 当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。...'
}
```

オブジェクト初期化子（リテラル）と関数式が混ざったような形になっていますが、こういった構文は JavaScript にはありません。
JavaScript の基礎の学習は前提として、ツール類の使い方として以下2点の改善をお勧めします。

- きちんとインデントしてくれて、できれば構文エラーなども指摘してくれるエディタを使う
- 常にブラウザの開発者ツールに出ているエラーなどを確認する

---

追記されたコードは HTML（テンプレート）部分が断片的なのでなんとも言えないですが、とりあえず、気付いた点は以下3つです。

1. button 要素の中が空（変なボタンになると思います）
2. data の初期値と change メソッドで設定している値が同じ（両方「当社のダミー商品2つめを紹介します。」）なので仮に正しく動いてもなにも変化しない
3. change メソッドで `this` を忘れている

`v-text="headding"` が解らないのであれば、まず[ドキュメント](https://jp.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-text)を参照し、それでも解らなければ別の質問として投稿して下さい。

Comment: <p>
       {{ description1 }}
      </p>

という形が多いですが v-text="headding"という形でも同じことが出来るという事でしょうか？オブジェクトのバリューに関数が入る形はJSでは存在しないのでエラーになるという事でしょうか？

Comment: 教えていただいたものを参考に変更しましたがやはりうまくいきません質問欄に記載しましたのでご確認いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: @mjy追記見ていただけましたか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。this.headdingのthisは<div id="app">の子要素であるv-text="headding"の中に指定のテキストを入れるという意味でよいでしょうか?

Comment: @nicomesecond  結果としては、おっしゃる通りの事が起きるはずです。メソッドの仕様は、まず[ドキュメント](https://jp.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods) を読んで、解らなければ質問として投稿して下さい。

Comment: 結果としてはという事は仕様の理解としては間違っているのですね